# Onclick open online chat support

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I am using a third party chat plugin on my site I just placed its javascript code on my site. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var __lc = {};
  __lc.license = 1812482;

  (function() {
    var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
    lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Now I have a image on my site I would like when someone click on that image then chat window should open. How to call this function by clicking on that image.

```
<img src="click_to_chat.png" onclick=""/>
```

Comment: Thats anonymous function and cannot be called explicitly, if you want to call it then give it a name

Comment: That's an anonymous function that is run when the browser parses the JavaScript. There is no way to "run" that function.

Comment: Did you get in touch with `LiveChatInc` at all? I assume you are trying out the 30-day trial? Besides, how is this PHP?

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 9):

If someone is still wondering this, for me, it works like so:

```
<button onclick="LC_API.open_chat_window();return false">Open Chat</button>
```

You need to have the LiveChat script tag loaded by the time you use the varible `LC_API`

Comment: Works nicely! Thanks

Comment: As mentioned here: [livechat.com](https://developers.livechat.com/docs/extending-chat-widget/javascript-api#methods), you can use: 
`LiveChatWidget.call("maximize");`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var __lc = {};
  __lc.license = 1812482;

$("#yourImage").one("click",function(){      
    var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
    lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give the function a name (and I assume not auto-execute it):

```
function initializeChat() {
    var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
    lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
};
```

Then you can call it any time you'd like:

```
initializeChat();
```

For example, you say you want to run this when you click on an image.  Something like this:

```
<img src="someImage" alt="someText" id="chatImage" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image = document.getElementById('chatImage');
    image.onclick = function () {
        initializeChat();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: @SonyG: Can you be more specific than that?  In what way does it not work?  Is there an error?  Can you provide a more complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @SonyG: I'm afraid "it's not working" isn't a meaningful description of the problem.  You'll have to do some debugging.  You can step through the code in a browser debugger (such as FireBug or Chrome developer tools) and find more information about specifically where/how it's failing.  But in general the concept itself works fine, demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/XF5Zg/